# Concatenate and hash all fields in flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a flow that adds two columns to existing columns. The first is the MD5 hash from the key fields, the second is the MD5 hash from all the others. The number of fields (both key and all others) may vary. I think i can pass the list of the keys and data fields via flow parameters, for example, KeyFields will be store keys columns metadata and DataFields metadata of all other columns. I try to find a function for the DerivedColumn activity, something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
md5(foreach(key:$KeyFields) { concat(concatKeys,key) })
```

May be there is another way to do it ?
My flow is

Azure Blob Storage (csv) -> DerivedColumn -> Azure Blob Storage (csv)

Answer (score 0):

You could try below idea:

step1: Use [LookUp Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to get the data from your Azure Blob Storage.

step2: Pass the data into [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity). In the Azure Function, you could do the md5 operation with .net code or other language.

step3:Pass the output of Azure Function into Copy Activity as source, and configure the Blob Storage as sink.